# so I am new to java and wrote this code. why it gives me error?

Tags: java

```
package java_learning;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("what is your name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("hello"+name);
        
        
                
    }

}
```

the error is
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
scanner cannot be resolved to a type

```
at java_learning.main.main(main.java:7)
```

Comment: Need to `import java.util.Scanner;` Also note that it's **S**canner, not **s**canner.

Comment: `new Scanner` with a capital `S`. Use an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij to avoid these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all import the package

`import java.util.Scanner`

Then just change the `new scanner()` to `new Scanner()`

Final code :

```java
package java_learning;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("what is your name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("hello"+name);
        
        
                
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got an typo in this line:

```
Scanner scanner = new scanner(System.in);
```

It needs to be:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: ok I changed it but still I have the error

Comment: Make sure you import the correct scanner util as suggested by @Robby Cornelissen.

Answer (score 0):

Import this , **import java.util.scanner;** and the s in the new scanner is small, make it Big "S"

Answer (score 0):

You need to import this library as **import java.util.Scanner;** and update new scanner line as **new Scanner()**